# Documentation/Instructions for Arm?

Tags: nyx

Arm is noted on the Tor Project website as a supported project. However, I cannot find any documentation about how to use and/or configure it. Is there a general guide or set of instructions for this?

Comment: Do you find anything helpful on this website https://www.atagar.com/arm/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Arm includes within itself a readme...

https://gitweb.torproject.org/arm.git/blob/HEAD:/README